# On blur event not working gives error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On blur event not working give error which written below.I just simply want to multiply the value in two textboxs.What i am doing wrong.

```
 TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null .  
 var txt8 = document.getElementById("txtQuantity").value;   

<script type="text/javascript">
function CalcSellPrice2() {

    var txt8 = document.getElementById("txtQuantity").value;
    var txt9 = document.getElementById("txtUnit").value;
    document.getElementById("TextBox10").value = txt8 + txt9;
    document.getElementById(txtTotal).innerHTML = TotalPriceValue;
    }


</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="span6" 
                                          onblur="CalcSellPrice2();"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `TextBox` is `asp.net` control so you should have to use `ClientID` in order to acces your asp controls because `asp.net` rander HTML with markup and concatenating the `ID` values of each parent naming container with the `ID` value of the control (Refer to [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)) as

```
<%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>
```

So your script is look like this

```
var txt8 = document.getElementById(" <%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>").value;
```

**OR**

The other way to access `ASP.NET` controls is to use attribute `ClientIDMode`, once you set it to `Static` it doesn't concatenate `ID` values of each parent naming container. so your HTML will look like as follows.

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="span6" onblur="CalcSellPrice2();"></asp:TextBox>
```

in this way you can simply access your asp controls as you have used in your question without using `ClientID`

Answer (score 0):

add attribute **ClientIDMode="Static"** to textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="span6" 
                                          onblur="CalcSellPrice2();"></asp:TextBox>
```